# Selecting column names and table names of a select statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How can I select the column name and table name from a SQL?

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
select column_name, table_name from (select * from users);
```

This might sound silly, but I have a list of different SQLs and I need to extract their columns and tables into a list. So some of the statements could me:

```
select username, password from users
select createdate from userlog
select * from dept
...
```

If I can select the column name and table name of a select statement, then I should get, say for the first statement, `username` and `password` for *columns* and `users` for *table name*. And `createdate` for *column* and `userlog` for *table name* in the second statement.

Then if it all works, I can then loop through the list of select statements and extract their column and table names.

Comment: you can try the view user_tab_cols

Comment: @psaraj12 I tried this but it didn't work too: `select user_tab_cols, table_name from (select * from users);`

Answer (score 1):

The below query worked for `Oracle database.`

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
```

You can see more about [**information-schema**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.0/information-schema.html)

**Edit:**

You may try like this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN (SELECT ColumnName FROM users)
```

Comment: This will give a lot of columns - use `user_tab_columns` if you want all tables that your user can see or add a `WHERE table_name='USERS'` for example. There is also a `COLUMN_ID` column that gives you the order of the columns in the table.

Comment: umm... but this doesn't let me pull out the table and column names of a specific select statement. This one just lists all tables in the DB, or filter using the where clause.

Comment: @VigneshKumar Thanks, I just tried, but it returned 0 rows. Also, when I use it on `select * from users`, I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the SQL statement so the SQL engine figures out the columns and datatypes of the columns that the statement returns.

How you do it best depends on what environment you are using. In some programming languages when you create a SqlPreparedStatement or OraCommand or whatever the object may be called, that object may have a metadata collection populated with column information after parsing.

If you are doing it in the database itself, parsing your statement with DBMS_SQL can get you the information you need. See Example 8 in the documentation at this link:

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68205

--

Oh, and this gives you column names of the select statement. The table names I do not know of any way to get easily.